# Firebird SQL: Subquery within an ALTER statement?

Tags: sql, subquery, firebird, alter-table

I have a firebird database schema which was set up by various `CREATE TABLE` scripts. These scripts have been commited to a source control system (see [Scott Allen's](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2008/02/03/versioning-databases-branching-and-merging.aspx) sites).

Now I want to create a new script in which I want my database to drop the `NOT NULL` constraint for one column in a specific table:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable DROP CONSTRAINT c
```

The constraint's name (e.g. INTEG_219) can be obtained by a query to a system table:

```
SELECT rc.rdb$constraint_name
FROM   rdb$relation_constraints rc
       join rdb$check_constraints cc
       on rc.rdb$constraint_name = cc.rdb$constraint_name
WHERE  rc.rdb$constraint_type   = 'NOT NULL'
       and rc.rdb$relation_name = 'MYTABLE'
       and cc.rdb$trigger_name  = 'ACOLUMN'
```

Can these statements be combined to a single `ALTER` command?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I advice you to take a look at [EXECUTE STATEMENT](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-psql-execstat.html).

and here in the [firebird faq](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq1/)

```
execute BLOCK 
as declare variable stmt VARCHAR(2500) = 'SELECT ''ALTER TABLE MYTABLE myTable DROP CONSTRAINT ''|| rc.rdb$constraint_name||'';'' FROM   rdb$relation_constraints rc
           join rdb$check_constraints cc
           on rc.rdb$constraint_name = cc.rdb$constraint_name WHERE  rc.rdb$constraint_type   = ''NOT NULL''
           and rc.rdb$relation_name = ''MYTABLE''
           and cc.rdb$trigger_name  = ''ACOLUMN'''; 
begin   
  execute STATEMENT stmt; 
end;
```

Comment: This seems to return the right string, including the name of the constraint. Unfortunately, EXECUTE STATEMENT ... doesn't work. Can you tell me how to execute the returned string?

Comment: do you try with execute block ?

Comment: Now I figured it out: EXECUTE block
AS
DECLARE VARIABLE stmt VARCHAR(255);
BEGIN
  FOR ... INTO :stmt
  DO
    EXECUTE STATEMENT :stmt;
END

Comment: I use Firebird 2.5 and within and execute block 'alter table ....' wasnt working and I changed to executre statement and it worked. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on Hughes Van Landeghem's answer and Norbert's response to that answer, so feel free not to vote it up :)

```
execute BLOCK 
as 
    declare variable stmt VARCHAR(2500); 
    declare variable cname varchar(255);
begin
    SELECT rc.rdb$constraint_name
        FROM   rdb$relation_constraints rc
               join rdb$check_constraints cc
               on rc.rdb$constraint_name = cc.rdb$constraint_name
        WHERE  rc.rdb$constraint_type   = 'NOT NULL'
               and rc.rdb$relation_name = 'MYTABLE'
               and cc.rdb$trigger_name  = 'ACOLUMN'
        INTO :cname;
    stmt = 'alter table myTable drop constraint ' || cname;
    execute STATEMENT stmt; 
end;
```

I'm also using Firebird 2.5 and could not get Hughes Van Landeghem's original answer to run.  The error I got was **No message for error code 335544928 found**, and I think it has something to do with the embedded select.